# Parse right of last found from email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have emails with the following type:

[image]

I am extracting the NAME and CITY but I want to extract also the problem for each field : NAME Because is WRONG and CITY Because it can't be READ

Until now I can extract one problem overall for each email - the first encounter.

```
Sub Problems()
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.items
    Dim myitem As Object
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myitems = GetFolderPatharchive("aaa\bbb").items
    Found = False

    Dim olkMsg As Object, _
        olkFld As Object, _
        excApp As Object, _
        excWkb As Object, _
        excWks As Object, _
        intRow As Integer, _
        intCnt As Integer, _
        data_email As String, _
        strFilename As String, _
        arrCells As Variant, _
        varb As Variant, varD As Variant, varF As Variant

    strFilename = "C:\OVERVIEW\EXTRACT EMAIL1"
    If strFilename <> vbNullString Then
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
        Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
        excApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        With excWks
            .Cells(1, 1) = "SENDER"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "SUBJECT"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "CITY"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "DATE"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "HOUR"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "FIELD"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "PROBLEM"
        End With

        intRow = 2

        For Each olkMsg In myitems
            If olkMsg.Class <> olMail Then
            Else
                arrCells = Split(GetCells(olkMsg.HTMLBody), Chr(255))
                For intCnt = LBound(arrCells) To UBound(arrCells) Step 1

On Error GoTo Handler
                    varb = arrCells(intCnt)
                    Dim line As Integer
                    line = InStr(olkMsg.Subject, "-")

                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.SenderName
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, line - 1)
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, 4)
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "dd.mm.yyyy")
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 5) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "Hh:Nn:Ss")
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 6) = varb

                    Dim strAddr As String
                    strAddr = ParseTextLinePair(olkMsg.Body, "WRONG")
                    If strAddr <> vbNullString Then excWks.Cells(intRow, 7) = "WRONG"

                    intRow = intRow + 1
                Next intCnt
            End If
Label1:
        Next olkMsg

        Set olkMsg = Nothing
        excWkb.SaveAs strFilename, 52
        excWkb.Close
    End If

    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "TA DAM! EMAILS EXPORTED", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Call opexlN
Exit Sub
Handler:
    Resume Label1
End Sub



Function ParseTextLinePair _
  (strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = _
              Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function



Function GetFolderPatharchive(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPatharchive_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPatharchive = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPatharchive = oFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolderPatharchive_Error:
    Set GetFolderPatharchive = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function


Private Function GetCells(strHTML As String) As String
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
    Dim objIE As Object, objDoc As Object, colCells As Object, objCell As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop
    objIE.Document.body.innerHTML = strHTML
    Set objDoc = objIE.Document
    Set colCells = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
    If colCells.Length > 0 Then
        For Each objCell In colCells
            GetCells = GetCells & objCell.innerText & Chr(255)
        Next
        GetCells = Left(GetCells, Len(GetCells) - 1)
    Else
        GetCells = ""
    End If
Set objCell = Nothing
Set colCells = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I've edited your code to **properly indent it** (it was almost unreadable), also take the habit of **specifying your variable on the `Next` statements** (ie `For Each olkMsg In ...` => `Next olkMsg`).  And we won't be able to answer your question **without rewriting almost everything, if you don't tell us what are the functions `GetCells` and `ParseTextLinePair`**. Furthermore, why do you `Dim i As String`, put 1 in it and don't use it??

Comment: Hi, thank you for editing. I added the GetCells , ParseTextLinePair , GetFolderPatharchive. i was  from a previous attempt .

Comment: Can you edit with image of the your email without sensitive  information?

Comment: @R3uK If you do more than indenting code in an edit, there is the risk of having nothing to answer. It would be unlikely to have been approved.

Comment: @niton : I know, I've started modifying it in the objective to answer but discovered the custom functions in the mean time. I haven't done much (nothing meaningful), but I see in the edit history that it has changed a lot of keywords' case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
Sub Problems()
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.items
    Dim myitem As Object
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myitems = GetFolderPatharchive("aaa\bbb").items
    Found = False

    Dim olkMsg As Object, _
        olkFld As Object, _
        excApp As Object, _
        excWkb As Object, _
        excWks As Object, _
        intRow As Integer, _
        intCnt As Integer, _
        data_email As String, _
        strFilename As String, _
        arrCells As Variant, _
        varB As Variant, varD As Variant, varF As Variant

    strFilename = "C:\OVERVIEW\EXTRACT EMAIL1"
    If strFilename <> vbNullString Then
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
        Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
        excApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        With excWks
            .Cells(1, 1) = "SENDER"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "SUBJECT"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "CITY"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "DATE"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "HOUR"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "FIELD"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "PROBLEM"
        End With 'excWks

        intRow = 2

        For Each olkMsg In myitems
            If olkMsg.Class <> olMail Then
            Else
                arrCells = Split(GetCells(olkMsg.HTMLBody), Chr(255))
                For intCnt = LBound(arrCells) To UBound(arrCells) Step 1

On Error GoTo Handler
                    varB = arrCells(intCnt)
                    Dim LgLocCell As Long
                    LgLocCell = InStr(1, olkMsg.Body, varB)
                    Dim LgLocReason As Long
                    LgLocReason = InStr(LgLocCell + Len(varB), olkMsg.Body, "because", vbTextCompare) + 6

                    Dim line As Integer
                    line = InStr(olkMsg.Subject, "-")
                    With excWks
                        .Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.SenderName
                        .Cells(intRow, 2) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, line - 1)
                        .Cells(intRow, 3) = Left(olkMsg.Subject, 4)
                        .Cells(intRow, 4) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "dd.mm.yyyy")
                        .Cells(intRow, 5) = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "Hh:Nn:Ss")
                        .Cells(intRow, 6) = varB
                        .Cells(intRow, 7) = Trim(Mid(olkMsg.Body, LgLocReason, InStr(LgLocReason + 1, olkMsg.Body, ".") - LgLocReason))
                    End With 'excWks
                    intRow = intRow + 1
                Next intCnt
            End If
Label1:
        Next olkMsg

        Set olkMsg = Nothing
        excWkb.SaveAs strFilename, 52
        excWkb.Close
    End If

    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "TA DAM! EMAILS EXPORTED", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Call opexlN
Exit Sub
Handler:
    Resume Label1
End Sub
```

---

Your function wasn't right, in case you didn't find `vbCrLf` you were putting a string inside the integer `intLocLabel` which would cause a Type Mismatch error! 
I'm not sure what you want to do when you don't find the line return, because your `Mid()` in that case is only returning 1 character after the text you were looking for!
I set it to return an empty string! ;)

```
Function ParseTextLinePair _
  (strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            'strText = _
              Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
            strText = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

Comment: You, SIR, are AWESOME !